# ElectronJS: Uncaught TypeError: ipcRenderer.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, electron

***Using: Electron v15.2.0 using the [Electron Quick Start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start)***

I know this is a very simple problem, but I can't seem to find a solution for it. Here's the code.

**main.js:**

```
// Get Tasks
ipcMain.on('json:get', (event, dataset) => {

  // Read the JSON file
  fs.readFile('./data/data.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {

    // Throw error to console if there is one
    if (err) {
      console.log("File read failed:", err)
      return
    }

    console.log(`JSON Data: ${jsonString}`)

    // Send returned JSON data to mainWindow
    mainWindow.webContents.send('tasks.return', jsonString)

  })
})
```

**preload.js:**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', ipcRenderer)
```

**renderer.js**

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('json:get', 'tasks')
})

ipcRenderer.on('tasks.return', (event, json) => {
    console.log(json)
})
```

What's happening is that the event listener is firing correctly, I know that because the JSON will dump into the console from the `main.js` code, but it's not firing from the `renderer.js` code. And I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: ipcRenderer.on is not a function`, but it's being called on:

```
ipcRenderer.on('tasks.return', (event, json) => {
    console.log(json)
})
```

But, it's not being called with the event listener fires.

I tried adding:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { ipcRenderer } = electron
```

To `renderer.js`, but then I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ipcRenderer' has already been declared` and neither work.

I know that I need to shorten the scope of the contextBridge and ipcRenderer in the `preload.js` file, and I will, but the issue is that I can't get the Electron app to send messages back to the mainWindow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where has `ipcRenderer` already been declared? Is it somewhere else in renderer.js?

Comment: oh wait renderer is the script that the preload script is injected into in this case, right? Also, maybe this is just an example, but you shouldn't expose the entire `ipcRenderer` object to the script. That's a security vulnerability (oh that might be what you meant by your last sentence)

Comment: what if you did the ipcRenderer.on stuff inside of the preload script instead and had it just trigger some callback that renderer.js sends to preload via a new API

Comment: @pushkin you're a genius! Moving the ipcRenderer.on to the `preload.js` works! I don't know why, but it does, so that's something! Thank you! And, yes, I was talking about the exposed `ipcRenderer` in the last sentence. I just want to get it working before I add variables to go wrong.

Comment: I think this is a good hack, but it seems wrong to me that we can't out those responses in the `renderer.js` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're seeing [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21437). `ipcRenderer` does not have an `on` method when in a (context-isolation-enabled?) renderer.

The solution is to move the `ipcRenderer.on` logic inside of the preload script like so (full code example [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21437#issuecomment-573522360)):

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    onResponse: (fn) => {
        ipcRenderer.on("tasks.return", (event, ...args) => fn(...args));
    }
});
```

And then your renderer can do:

```
window.api.onResponse((json) => console.log(json));
```

(keep in mind the memory leak for which a solution is mentioned [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21437#issuecomment-802288574))

Comment: what did you Google to get there? I spent a couple hours last night trying different variations and could not get to that answer!

Comment: @coffeepostal I'd recommend searching the github issues. I vaguely recalled something like this and did [this search](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues?q=is%3Aissue+ipcrenderer.on+renderer+is%3Aclosed)